# How check value existence in a deeply nested array in MongoDB.Driver C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

As the following image, the collection is `Posts`. The `_id`s for the post and the comment are known.

So, How to check if a given value `d` exists in the `AgreedUserIds`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this for single character search:

```js
db.Posts.find(
    {
        _id: "b4d5...ff79",
        Comments: {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id: "c1ea...d45",
                AgreedUserIds: "d"
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And this for multi character search:

```js
db.Posts.find(
    {
        _id: "b4d5...ff79",
        Comments: {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id: "c1ea...d45",
                AgreedUserIds: { $in: ["c", "d"] }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: `AgreedUserIds` itself is an array. Does it need an extra `$elemMatch` for `AgreedUserIds`?

Comment: No. Its an array of characters so not required.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading. `AgreedUserIds` is allowed to contain strings longger than a single character.

Comment: Use `$elemMatch` only when an array contains objects.

Comment: The `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array. `AgreedUserIds: { $in: ["c", "d"] }` should mean `AgreedUserIds=="c" || AgreedUserIds=="d"` instead of `"c" in AgreedUserIds || "d" in AgreedUserIds`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it `BsonDocument` you have options to combine filters like this>

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("posts");
var postId = new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId("604b5ff389ff6887d1b91a93"));
var commentId = new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId("604b5ff389ff6887d1b91a92"));
var userId = "a";
//var userId = "e"; // not found
var postIdMatches = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", postId);
var commentIdMatches = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", commentId);
var userIdInside = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.AnyEq("AgreedUserIds", userId); // "a" in checking
var commentCheck = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch("Comments", userIdInside & commentIdMatches); // & combines filters. Also ElemMatch on any of the Comments is passing the criteria
var rows = (await collection.FindAsync<BsonDocument>(postIdMatches & commentCheck)).ToList();
```

You could also `GetCollection<Post>` with C# Post class describing the Post business object, and use .Any Linq query on that.